# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function In AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, bower-install

My app is Working Fine. But I used color picker from http://ruhley.github.io/angular-color-picker/ and some thing went wrong.Now my app is unable to start also. I removed this color picker still same.
error I am getting is

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function inside angular.js at

function createInternalInjector(cache, factory) {

```
function getService(serviceName, caller) {
  if (cache.hasOwnProperty(serviceName)) {
    if (cache[serviceName] === INSTANTIATING) {
      throw $injectorMinErr('cdep', 'Circular dependency found: {0}',
                serviceName + ' <- ' + path.join(' <- '));
    }
    return cache[serviceName];
  } else {
    try {
      path.unshift(serviceName);
      cache[serviceName] = INSTANTIATING;
      return cache[serviceName] = factory(serviceName, caller);
    } catch (err) {
      if (cache[serviceName] === INSTANTIATING) {
        delete cache[serviceName];
      }
      throw err;//<<------GETTING ERROR HERE
    } finally {
      path.shift();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's saying the function getservice is not a function? which part exactly is it pointing to as undefined

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by updating angular-cookies and angular-resource both to 1.4.0